# Programmatically close Windows console application c++

Tags: c++, windows, mutex, handle

I need my windows console application to be run only in one instance (i.e. Only one instance of the application can be run at a time).
Here's what I have:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    PCTSTR Name = TEXT("AnyName");
    HANDLE h = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, Name);

    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
    {
        _tprintf_s(TEXT("This application is already opened."));
        CloseHandle(h);
        // Close the console somehow
        return 0;
    }
    else _tprintf_s(TEXT("The application has been opened the first time."));

    _gettchar();
    return 0;
}
```

How can I programmatically close the console window if the same program is already initialized?

Comment: bring the other instance to the front and let this instance simply exit.

Comment: You shouldn't try to close the console Window--just exit as you are doing.  If your program owns its console, it will close automatically.  If it does not (such as when your program is launched from a dos box), then the window will remain open as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can hide it by

```
ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);
```

Although I really think you should quit the program instead just closing the console.

Comment: So, how do I quit the program?

Comment: So I run your program from an existing console and it hides my window? Funny. Not nice, but funny.

Comment: this is funny, but this is also something he asked, he should take that as a consideration. or do what I also suggested - just quit nicely

Comment: @DavidHaim I'll do the nice quitting:)

Answer (score 1):

_gettchar() is used to stop the console from closing, thus only allowing it when you want to keep the console open will mean if you want it to close, it will:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    PCTSTR Name = TEXT("AnyName");
    HANDLE h = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, Name);

    if (GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS)
    {
        _tprintf_s(TEXT("This application is already opened."));
        CloseHandle(h);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
         _tprintf_s(TEXT("The application has been opened the first time."));
         _gettchar();
    }
    return 0;
}
```